# How do I place a breakpoint at the start of an application in LLDB

Tags: debugging, lldb

Whenever I try and debug an application with LLDB I can not seem to get a breakpoint set at the entry point of the application.

I have been running `br set -n _main` and this sets a breakpoint that can be seen when running `br list` however these breakpoints are never hit.

How do I get LLDB to set a breakpoint at the entry point of my executable?

Comment: Note, BTW, lldb breakpoints always set (as opposed to gdb) since the symbol you are looking for may come from a shared library that isn't loaded yet.  To lldb, breakpoints are "specifiers" and "breakpoint locations" are the places the specifier found.  If the `br list` output doesn't show any "locations" in the listing, then nothing matched your specifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you launch your process using:

```
(lldb) process launch --stop-at-entry -- <Process arguments>
```

that will stop when your program binary is loaded, but before any code is run.  Note, that includes any dyld code - so no shared libraries have been loaded, only the main executable - or any system initializers.  So there's generally not much you can do safely at this point.  If you want to then stop at the first significant library load, you can do:

```
(lldb) target.process.stop-on-sharedlibrary-events 1
(lldb) continue
```

That will run to the first major load event (and stop at all the others if you leave it on.)

Comment: How do you place a instruction level breakpoint at entry in LLDB? In gdb I can simply do `starti`, but I didn't find anything equivalent in LLDB yet.

Comment: In lldb, stop-at-entry is not implemented by breakpoints because the process, when being launched under the debugger, stops at the entry point by itself as part of the debugging startup contract, so a breakpoint isn't necessary.  Do you want a breakpoint so you can hook some action to the entry point?  If so, you can use a one-shot stop-hook for that purpose.