LLDB can't list function nor set a breakpoint
I'm having some trouble using lldb, I want to set a breakpoint for a macho file at the start label and at a function called Function1. Ideally i'd like to list all the functions like in gdb with the 'info functions' command, but it seems that this is not available in lldb. Anyways, when I try to set a breakpoint I get this:
breakpoint set --name start
Breakpoint 3: 22 locations

Then if I run the binary, the breakpoint doesn't get hit, it just executes and quits, what gives? Also why does it show "22 locations" there should only be one entry point named start.

This might be useful (in fact yours might be a duplicate of it): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73363945/how-do-i-place-a-breakpoint-at-the-start-of-an-application-in-lldb

@matt what if you want to set a bp at a given function, the answer you linked only works when it's the entry point.

That seems to be what you're asking about. No?

I think the "22 locations" thing is because "start" exists in multiple modules (the exe and dylibs).  If you use yourexe\start` you will get different results; however I played around with this myself and couldn't get it to work...

lldb's breakpoints aren't quite like gdb breakpoints.  An lldb breakpoint is a "search query" that stays alive till you delete the breakpoint, and makes "breakpoint locations" for all matches to the query.
The default breakpoint type (-n) is an eager search, so:
(lldb) break set -n start

will match start MyClass::start, -[MyClass start] etc.  If you want to have an exact match, use break set -f.  You might take a look at:
(lldb) help break set

for more information on how lldb breakpoints work.
On Darwin, most programs don't actually have a start symbol anymore.  You can see that by running:
 $ nm <my_binary> | grep start

After all, only the loader needs that symbol and it can just record the initial address in its data structures in the binary and avoid a symbol lookup.
If you want the binary to stop at it's entry point, use:
(lldb) process launch --stop-at-entry

That will work anywhere.
If you want to list the symbols in a binary, use:
(lldb) image dump symtab <Image Name>

If you are used to gdb, you might have a look at:
https://lldb.llvm.org/use/map.html
